# Flask - how to call python function with parameters in button?

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working on a notification system on my website. I decided to make a model in the database for them. I also made a function in views.py that takes an argument of a user that is receiving a notification and the type of notification.  Here is the code:

```
@views.route('/send_notification',methods = ['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def send_notification(user, type):

    reciever = User.query.filter_by(username = user).first()

    if type == 'family-invitation':
        family = Family.query.filter_by(id = current_user.family_id).first()
        description = "invites you to their family!"
        new_notification = Notification(sender = current_user.username, sender_prof_img = family.prof_img, user_id = reciever.id, description = description)
        db.session.add(new_notification)
        db.session.commit()
        flash("Invitation to family has been sent!", category="success")

    return True
```

Now I want to be able to send the user a notification when someone invites them. I was thinking about calling the python function when someone presses the button but I don't know how to code it.

I came up with something like this but it doesn't work:

```
<button
      onclick="window.location.href = '{{ url_for('views.send_notification(profileUser.username, 'family-invitation')') }}';"
    >
      Invite to family
    </button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

url_for() in Flask Jinja templates does not work like that. It forms a URL to a specific resource, which means you can not pass Python code as a parameter.
The option that comes to my mind first is to use URL parameters for passing data to your route function.

```
@views.route('/send_notification/<user>/<type>',methods = ['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def send_notification(user, type):

    reciever = User.query.filter_by(username = user).first()

    if type == 'family-invitation':
        family = Family.query.filter_by(id = current_user.family_id).first()
        description = "invites you to their family!"
        new_notification = Notification(sender = current_user.username,                     
    sender_prof_img = family.prof_img, user_id = reciever.id, description = description)
    db.session.add(new_notification)
    db.session.commit()
    flash("Invitation to family has been sent!", category="success")

return True
```

So that your HTML would look like that:

```
<button
  onclick="btnOnClick(profileUser.username, 'family-invitation');"
    >
  Invite to family
</button>
<script>
    function btnOnClick(username, notificationType) {
    window.location = `/send_notification/${username}/${notificationType}`;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

### js file

```js
function myfunction(){
   fetch("/send_notification", {
      method:"GET"
})

}
```

---

html

```html
<button onclick="myfunction()">click me to send notification</button>
```